# What are the possible disadvantages of enabling the "data access" server option in sys.servers for the local server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, configuration

We plan to change the default server options of an SQL2k5 server instance by enabling data access.

The reason is that we want to run `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LOCALSERVER, '...')` - like statements on the server.

What are the possible disadvantages of enabling server option "data access" (alias `sys.servers.is_data_access_enabled`) for the local server (`sys.servers.server_id = 0`)?

(There must be a reason for MS setting this option to disabled by default...)

**EDIT:** it turns out that I'm not the first person to ask this question:

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/piotr_rodak/archive/2009/11/22/data-access-setting-on-local-server.aspx

> The DATA ACCESS server option is not very well documented in my opinion - the Books On Line say it is a property of linked servers. It doesn't mention at all that you actually can have it enabled on your local server to enable OPENQUERY calls. I noticed that when you disable DATA ACCESS on a linked server, you can't query any table located on it (I tested it on my loopback server) neither using OPENQUERY nor four-part naming convention. You can still call procedures (with four-part naming) that return rowsets. Well, the interesting question is why it is disabled by default on local server - I suppose to discourage users from using OPENQUERY against it.

[It also seems that the author of the post is a Stack Overflow user :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227606/)

**UPDATE:** [Another tech blogger ran into the same issue in 2014.](https://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/technical-microsoft-sql-server-transact-sql-linked-server-error-transaction-context-in-use-by-another-session-msg-3910-level-16-state-2-line-1/) [Also a Stackoverflow user.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023504/)

Answer (score 1):

*There must be a reason for MS setting this option to disabled by default..*

For a while now Microsoft products have taken the approach of trying to be 'secure out-of-the-box'.  This means that features, such as turning on data access for a linked server, needs to be explicitly turned on.  This prevents users (or admins) from inadvertently enabling an options which may be a security risk.

Comment: This is technically correct if speaking of real linked servers. This case is specific, however: I want to enable OPENQUERY-like access to the local server. With the right credentials, one can already do a lot of malicious business without this setting enabled. Well, except some exotic stuff, like fetching the result set of nested stored procedures. Not really the thing that a potential attacker would wish for, I guess.

Comment: Oh right. it's the local server your enabling this on?  One question is Why?  this is not ideal, your better off using four part naming if you want to access tables between databases & turning db ownership chaining on

Comment: "Well, except some exotic stuff, like fetching the result set of nested stored procedures." Which can prove to be a nontrivial problem when simply using four part naming and INSERT-EXEC, try googling "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested".
In my case, I want to query the execution status of jobs from a T-SQL script, for which the adequate facility seems to be sp_help_job (see http://www.microsoft.com/technet/abouttn/flash/tips/tips_060804.mspx). I want to use sp_help_job in an automated script, and fetch its result set with INSERT-EXEC, in which case I get the mentioned error message.